# shutdown in specific way, if no-one uses computer

Tags: shutdown, lubuntu

I have problem because my friends with I live often forget to shut down our computer. 
I don't know how solution use to pretend it. There is ubuntu system installed.

I am looking for solution that user will be force to click and confirm (once a hour) that someone uses computer. If he doesn't it computer automatically should do shutdown.

Is there any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a working script of what you want to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
   sleep 59m
   zenity --question --text "Are you using the pc (click anything)?"&
   zenity_id=$!
   #the user has 1 minute to answer, otherwise PC will shut down
   sleep 1m
   if kill $zenity_id 2> /dev/null; then 
      #zenity was still running, shutdown the pc
      dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.RequestShutdown
   fi
done
```

Every once an hour it displays a pop-up asking 'Are you still here?', if the user clicks on something, then it doesn't shutdown for another one hour (in one hour the pop-up is shown again), but if more than 1 minute passes without interaction with the dialog, then the PC automatically shuts down.
In order to start this on startup, create a file with the above code and make it executable (right click->properties->permissions->allow executing file as program) and click on the power button to the top right of your screen, select startup applications and add this script.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to emulate a press of the power button. Then the following dialog will pop up, and shut down the computer after 60 seconds.
[image]

To do this, use `acpi_fakekey 116` which will "press" the shutdown button (number 116). (At least 116 is my shutdown button. If it fails on your machine,try installing `evtest` and run it while you press the button)

To automate this every hour, add it to roots crontab like this:

`sudo crontab -e` and add the following line:

`0 *  *   *   *   /usr/bin/acpi_fakekey 116`

This will press the button at the 0th minute of every hour of every day of every week of every month.

Comment: Thanks, your advice is helpful, but realized that on this computer lubuntu is installed and it doesn't work the same like in ubuntu because I see new frame with options but there is not automatic time to shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

You could [write a simple script](http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php) using the command `shutdown 0` after a prompt.

I should add you can use the [sleep command](https://superuser.com/questions/222301/unix-sleep-until-the-specified-time) in a loop to realize the waiting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems tedious to make someone click a button every specified interval.

You could let gnome-screensaver work for you and check how long it's been running.

In a script, you could do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

pidof X || exit #not running X!

export DISPLAY=":0" # use current display
DURATION="`gnome-screensaver-command -t | awk '{print $7}'`"

if [ $DURATION -gt 3600 ]; then #idle for an hour
  shutdown -h now
fi
```

This is a VERY basic example that anyone could expand on.  Place it in a cron job or run it in a daemon mode with while/sleep calls.

I would not use it exactly as-is, but just to illustrate a method.  This makes the assumption we're using gnome-screensaver.  xscreensaver has similar calls.